# Node.js - Is it acceptable to save a file stream to disk, solely for the purpose of getting the file length?

Tags: node.js

I have multiple Node.js servers running on my backend. One is an API server, which can accept image files from a 3rd party. The image files are streamed to the stdin of an ImageMagick process, and then the stdout of the ImageMagick process is streamed to a Node.js TCP server where the file is ultimately saved locally. The TCP server then needs to send a response to the API server after the file is successfully saved, so I need some way for the TCP server to know when it has the entire file (i.e. I can't simply close the socket on the API server after the file is sent).

One solution I could use is to save the stdout of the ImageMagick process to a temporary file on the API server, so I can get the length of the full file before I send it, and embed it in the beginning of the stream. Writing to disk throws a bit of a knot in the system though.

Is it acceptable to write a temp file to disk for the purpose of getting the length of the file, or is there a better / more efficient way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't the stream from the imagemagick processing ending enough of a signal to the TCP server that it has all the data?

Comment: The ImageMagick process is on the API server. The Node.js TCP server is on a separate physical server, which is used for static content (it's just used to save the file, and then communicate back with the API server).

Comment: Just to clarify, the ImageMagick stream goes through the API server, not directly to the TCP server. If the ImageMagic output is streamed to the API server, there's no way of getting the size in advance (at least not that I'm aware of).

Comment: But it's a user upload, isn't it? The very first server should already know how many bytes it's going to receive before the first packet of actual file data arrives: that number should already be the `Content-Length` header, because your server needs to be able to tell whether the client transfer broke (either prematurely, or erroneously sending bad data, etc). Record that number and forward it on?

Comment: Yeah, it's a user upload, but the API server then takes the image and runs it through ImageMagick. It's the output stream of the ImageMagick process that then gets sent to the TCP server, and the ImageMagick output stream is a different size than the input. I'm not aware of any way to get the size of the ImageMagick output stream without first saving it to disk.

Comment: Hm. Is there a reason you're running this as a stream rather than as "send data, then run image magic on in-memory data, then check in-memory result for size and send it back"?

Comment: Yeah, I considered doing that, but the image files can be pretty large, and many images can be processed at once, so I'm trying to stream everything through Node to reduce the memory footprint. I think I might have found a pretty simple workaround though, which avoids the need to specify the image size altogether. I'm playing around with it a bit, and if it works out, I'll post an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody else with a similar problem stumbles upon this, I found an alternative solution, which avoids the need to specify the file size altogether.

Create the TCP server using the {allowHalfOpen: true} option. The client can send the file to the TCP server, and then simply call the "end" method on the socket to signify that no more data will be written by the client (the socket is still readable by the client). With the "allowHalfOpen" option set on the server, the server can simply listen for the "end" event (which signifies that all of the data has been received), with the writable side of the server still open (allowing the server to send a response back to the client).

Note that the "allowHalfOpen" option defaults to false. If this option isn't set, the server automatically closes the socket when the writable side of the client is closed.

e.g.

SERVER

```
const fs = require('fs');
const net = require('net');
const server = net.createServer({allowHalfOpen: true});

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('myFile.png');

    socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
        writeStream.write(chunk);
    });

    socket.on('end', () => {
        writeStream.end();
        socket.end('File Written To Disk'); // send response and close socket
    });
});

server.listen(8000);
```

CLIENT

```
const fs = require('fs');
const net = require('net');

const socket = net.connect(8000);

fs.createReadStream('myFile.png').pipe(socket);

socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
    // response from TCP server
    console.log(chunk.toString()); // File Written To Disk
});

socket.on('end', () => {
    // server closed socket
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is relevant. But ImageMagick miff: format is a streaming format. So you can write the dimensions of the image to a text file while streaming it out again via miff:.

```
convert rose: miff:- | convert - -format "%wx%h" -write info:tmp.txt miff:-
```

Here I use `convert rose: miff:-` to simulate your input stream.

Then I pipe it to the next convert, which reads the input stream, writes the WxH information to a tmp.txt text file, which you could access subsequently. The second convert also creates a miff:- output stream.

You could use NetPBM format in place of miff, since it also is a streaming format.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with miff, but it sounds like I need to supply the information. Is there a way to get the size of the output file, or rather, inject the size of the output file into the beginning of the output stream (e.g. first 4 bytes of the output stream contain the file size, or something similar)?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the ambiguity in my question. By "size" I'm talking about the size of the image in bytes, not the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Change `%wx%h` to `%b` for the file size. I do not know how to inject that into the stream. I know little about streaming data.

Comment: I spent some more time reading up on miff, and it actually does embed metadata at the beginning of the file (which is what I'm trying to do), but it sounds like it's primarily for use with ImageMagick directly. I could stream the image output as miff, but then I'd have to parse the size and image binary out of the stream myself. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. It's the right idea, but I don't think it'll work for my particular scenario.

Comment: You could stream in NetPBM format either in binary or ascii format. That is a very simple format found on all Linux distributions. See http://netpbm.sourceforge.net and http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ and http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/#libnetpbm

Comment: Thanks, I read up on NetPBM and I don't think it does what I'm looking for. It's not the streaming itself that's the problem, but rather, the ability to inject custom headers / metadata in a deterministic way, at the beginning of the stream. It's easy to do if I simply write the ImageMagick output to disk (then I simply read the file size, and encode it in the first 3 bytes of the TCP stream), but that has the inherent bottleneck of writing to / reading from disk. I might just end up doing this though, as it's not looking like there's a simple alternative.